# Select users in relation with theire other table on rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

My users have one to many relation with my table "Bien" i want select only users who have biens in my result page

My controller is like this

```
def search
    @users = User.all
    @biens = Bien.near(params[:location], 3, units: :km).where(room_type: params[:room_type], nb_piece: params[:nb_piece])
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@bien) do |bien, marker|
      marker.lat @bien.latitude
      marker.lng @bien.longitude
    end
  end
```

I want select only users who have biens.near(....)
I try many solutions but i want know the good solution to get it

Thanks

Comment: Could you try checking if the `user_id` in the Bien object isn't `nil`? `Bien.where.not(user_id: nil)`

Comment: Thanks It works but its give me Biens where user is not nill but if i display users it will be all users but i want only users who have biens near of ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the User table to the bien table with something like this.
This will give you an inner join which will only show you the intersecting records...

If the user has many biens...

```
User.joins(:biens).where(...)
```

If the user has one bien...

```
User.joins(:bien).where(...)
```

This will give you a list of users who have biens...

You could then query further on the biens table to your liking:

```
User.joins(:biens).where('biens.room_type = ?', params[:room_type])
```

etc.

Comment: Alternate form: `where(biens: { room_type: params[:room_type] })`

Comment: Thanks for your help i will search in SQL docs, when i try the first form  users.size = biens.size even if only 2 users have these biens i will try the alternate form